# secure authentication between subdomains hosted seperately

Tags: audit, user-management, e-commerce, sub-domain

The web tools we are developing for a client require seamless interoperability with an existing user management sytem and commerce tools (the "mainsite").  The mainsite is built and maintained by a third party.  We've developed a plan to interact with this third party but are *not sure our plan is secure or how it could be improved*.

**Regarding Cookies**
All web pages will be hosted on subdomains of website.com.  Therefore, we should be able to read any cookies the mainsite's pages leave with the client.

**User Management**
Customers will continue to sign in using mainsite's existing user management system.  If a customer is anonymously visiting a page on our subdomain and require authentication, we will direct them to mainsite.  The url we use to direct customers to sign in will include a ReturnUrl parameter so customer's can be redirected once they are authenticated.

We will check if a customer is authenticated by checking for the presence of mainsite's session tracking cookie, then reading that session tracking cookie, then making a secure request to mainsite for more information about the customer associated with that session id.  We will need to know if the session is active and the customer's username.

**Commerce Tools**
We will build an api from which mainsite can pass in a username and we would return metadata about their shopping basket items.  Additional calls to the API could include requests for more information about shopping cart items.

**Regarding Security**
We've not performed a security audit on this proposal.  We suggest filtering all communication between our servers to whitelisted ip addresses.  All calls between our two sides should be encrypted.  *We may want to consider additional security to prevent unwanted snooping into customers' shopping carts by using their account names.*